# JSF 2 : noSelectionOption problem for selectOneMenu with converter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Im currently testing the use of **f:selectItems** tag that make use of existing POJO classes.

### This is working fine :

facelet :

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectionLabBean.oneSelectMenuPojo}" 
    converter="heroConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{selectionLabBean.heroList}" 
        var="hero" itemValue="#{hero}" itemLabel="#{hero.name}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

managed bean :

```
private HeroBean oneSelectMenuPojo;
public HeroBean getOneSelectMenuPojo() {
    return oneSelectMenuPojo;
}
public void setOneSelectMenuPojo(HeroBean oneSelectMenuPojo) {
    this.oneSelectMenuPojo = oneSelectMenuPojo;
}
```

### And then, i want to add "Choose one .." selection, i did this :

facelet :

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectionLabBean.oneSelectMenuPojo}" 
    converter="heroConverter">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="NONE" itemLabel="Choose one .." 
        noSelectionOption="true"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{selectionLabBean.heroList}" 
        var="hero" itemValue="#{hero}" itemLabel="#{hero.name}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and this will exception happens :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to user.ui.HeroBean

I think i understand the problem. Im using converter to map POJO to selection and the other way around and the "Choose one" maps to a String. But i also want to put the string of "Choose one ..". What can i do to solve this problem ?

Here's my converter class :

```
@FacesConverter("heroConverter")
public class HeroBeanConverter implements Converter {
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent ui, 
        String newValue) {
        return HeroBean.findHeroBeanByName(newValue);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) {
        return ((HeroBean) value).getName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of these should work:

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose one .." 
        noSelectionOption="true"/>

<f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Choose one .." 
        noSelectionOption="true"/>
```

Comment: @Albert: NullPointerException *where*? In the converter?

Comment: Sorry :) [#|2010-12-29T17:03:25.896+0700|WARNING|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8080-(2);|StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException at user.ui.HeroBeanConverter.getAsString(HeroBeanConverter.java:19)

Comment: Ahhhhhh solved it. Just made my converter more lenient by replacing the old line with this line : if (value == null) return ""; return ((HeroBean) value).getName(); Thank you sooo much !

Comment: Now in both cases it passess "Choose one .." to converter and I get "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-Choose one..""

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed that if you use the @FacesConverter forClass attribute instead of the value attribute then the noSelectionOption is ignored (getAsString isn't called for the noSelectionOption)!  This inconsistency seems like a bug, but it's worth mentioning.

In other words use:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass= HeroBean.class)
```

instead of

```
@FacesConverter("heroConverter")
```

(with converter="heroConverter" attribute on selectOneMenu)

At least this is what I've observed using Mojarra 2.0.2 on GlassFish 3.0.1.  Obviously in some situations you don't want all entities to use one converter so in that case this isn't a good idea.

Comment: Still the same with Mojarra 2.2.13 SP4 on a Wildfly 11.0.0 Final. Can't believe that.